# Join two tables and add the data with the same column id

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 4.2
I have two tables "questions" and "votes"
In my questions table I have columns like

- `id`,
- `id_user`,
- `subject`,
- `body`.

In my votes table I have columns like

- `id`,
- `id_question`,
- `id_user`,
- `likes`,
- `dislikes`.

The user is allowed to vote only once therefore the values for likes and dislikes for each user is 0-1, the `id_question` has the `id` of the question from the questions table. Now U want to sort the questions in the descending order according to the  number of votes cast for each question.

How do I sum the votes and sort them. This is what I have tried but it just displays me the count of the first question

```
$questions=Question::leftJoin('votes', 'questions.id', '=', 'votes.id_question')
            ->groupBy('questions.id')->sum('likes');

            return json_encode($questions);
```

after I get the counts i can sort them in the descending order by using `orderBy('likes','DESC')->get();`
but how to get the sum of likes?

Comment: As a side note, I think you may want to create a `like_counter` column in the questions table that keeps a current total of likes and dislikes.  It is a denormalization, but probably much faster as your DB grows.

Comment: after `->sum('likes')` add `->get();`

Comment: Gives me the following error "Call to a member function get() on a non-object" @evans_murithi

Comment: I will have to make so many changes if i add the column `like_counter` @CatoMinor

Comment: try this `$questions=Question::leftJoin('votes', 'questions.id', '=', 'votes.id_question')->sum('likes')->get();` without the group by and see if it returns something

Comment: Still gives me same error "Call to a member function get() on a non-object" and i type  `$questions=Question::leftJoin('votes', 'questions.id', '=', 'votes.id_question')->sum('likes')` it returns me the sum of all the likes in the table @evans_murithi

Comment: try adding `select` i.e. `->select('questions.id', 'votes.likes')->sum('likes')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82367/discussion-between-jht-and-evans-murithi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$questions=Question::leftJoin('votes', 'questions.id', '=', 'votes.id_question')
    ->select(DB::raw('questions.id, SUM(votes.likes) as likes'))
    ->groupBy('questions.id'‌​)
    ->get();
```